# spring MVC: problems in binding an enum value to an hidden field

Tags: java, spring-mvc, enums, hidden-field

I have issues in binding enum values in hidden fields with spring mvc.
The scenario is the following: I have a form with a list of documents which are characterized by a type.
My form class is (please note how the constructor is made. It fills the documents list with empty documents whose type is taken from the `DocumentType` enumeration):

```
public class Form {

    private List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<Document>();   

    //while creating this class, I instantiate a number
    //of empty documents with a certain type attribute
    public Form() {     
        super();
        for(DocumentType type : DocumentType.values())
        {
            Document document = new Document();
            document.setType(type);
            documents.add(document);
        }
    }
}
```

my document class is:

```
public class Document{

    private DocumentType type;
    private String expirationDate
    private URL link
    //getters & setters
}
```

while `DocumentType` is an ordinary enumeration

```
public enum DocumentType {

    TYPE_A("type a"),
    TYPE_B("type b"),
    TYPE_C("type c");

    private String literal;

    public String getLiteral() {
        return literal;
    }

    private StateDocumentType(String literal) {
        this.literal = literal;
    }   
}
```

I want to display a form of this kind (the rounded boxes are form fields):

[image: form to be shown]

so, in order to update the right document with the proper link and expiration date, I want to use an hidden field associated to every form input row.

So my jsp is the following:

```
<form:form role="form"  id="form" commandName="stateForm" action="${formUrl }">                     
    <c:forEach items="${form.documents }" var="document" varStatus="vs">
        <div id="doc_${document.type }>                     
            <label>${document.type.literal }</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <form:hidden path="documents[${vs.index }].type"/>                          
                <form:input type="text" path="documents[${vs.index }].link"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- omitted the exp. date part -->                             
    </c:forEach>    
</form:form>
```

here's the problem: when the html page is requested and rendered, the hidden field "`value`" attribute is just empty, while I expected it is valorized with the proper enum value. Please note that the parent `<div>` `id` is properly valorized. I really don't know why this doesn't work.

Comment: Why you are writing `documents[${vs.index }].type` not `document.type`?

Comment: because this is needed by Spring to perform the binding with the form object. I use `document.type` inside the for each loop to display values. When I need to bind variables, Spring requires the precise name of the variable in the model object. `document` is a jsp-scoped variable which is not recognized in the backend logic.

Comment: You can override `toString` method in your `DocumentType` enum.